# boost::ptr_vector and cloning objects

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use boost::ptr_vector, with an abstract base class but I am getting compile errors.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Clonable concept 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template< class T >
inline T* new_clone( const T& r )
{
    //
    // @remark: if you get a compile-error here,
    //          it is most likely because you did not
    //          define new_clone( const T& ) in the namespace
    //          of T.
    //
    T* res = new T( r );
    BOOST_ASSERT( typeid(r) == typeid(*res) &&
                  "Default new_clone() sliced object!" );
    return res;
}
```

I don't see why I need to provide a clone function. This is the whole reason I wanted a vector of pointers in the first place. It should copy the pointers and not need a clone function.

---

I think I've found the problem. I actually want a 2d vector of pointers, so I made a std::vector of boost::ptr_vector. But I take it the ptr_vector copy constructor performs a deep copy of the objects, hence the error? In the following code, if I uncomment any of the lines I get compile error C2259: 'Engine::IPlot' : cannot instantiate abstract class    C:\boost_1_48_0\boost\ptr_container\clone_allocator.hpp 34. But how else can I get a 2d array?

```
class World : public IWorld
{
public:
    World(const Engine::PairInt& plot_size);
    virtual ~World();

    virtual const Engine::PairInt& GetPlotSize() const;
    virtual Engine::IPlot *GetPlot(Engine::PairInt coord);
    virtual const Engine::IPlot *GetPlot(Engine::PairInt coord) const;

protected:
    typedef std::vector< boost::ptr_vector< IPlot > > PlotMap;
    PlotMap plot_map;
    const Engine::PairInt plot_size;
};

World::World(const PairInt& plot_size_in)
: plot_size(plot_size)
//, plot_map(GetPlotSize().y)
{
    PairInt plot_size = GetPlotSize();

    //plot_map.reserve(plot_size.y);
    for (int y = 0; y < plot_size.y; y++)
    {
        //plot_map.push_back(boost::ptr_vector< IPlot >());
        for (int x = 0; x < plot_size.x; x++)
        {
            plot_map[y].reserve(plot_size.x);
            plot_map[y].push_back(IPlot::Create(Vector2(PairInt(x, y).ToVector2()), true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 No compiler error message, confusing question. Do you want cloning support?

Comment: compile error C2259: 'Engine::IPlot' : cannot instantiate abstract class C:\boost_1_48_0\boost\ptr_container\clone_allocator.hpp 34. IT'S IN MY POST.

Comment: I don't want cloning support. I want a vector of pointers and the vector automatically deletes the pointers when it destructs. I'm trying to use boost ptr_vector which is hassling me with cloning support that I'm not familiar with hence the question. I've already figured it out, cloning is needed by the ptr_vector copy constructor as I have a vector of ptr_vector for a 2d array.

Comment: use ptr_vector of vectors or ptr_vector of ptr_vectors .  use ptr_map.   use manual indexing onto 1d vector.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal balls tell me you are using `resize`. Don't use it, use push_back or such.